# Detect path of font on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, fonts, fontconfig

I want know from name of font, the relative path on the system

I know with **fc-list** show list of all fonts with relative path, but exist a command to show me only a font I need ?

I tried **fc-match** but result is something weird and not show full path of font

```
salsan@DESKTOP-E2MG55K:/mnt/s/GitHub/otu$ fc-match FreeMono
FreeMono.ttf: "FreeMono" "Regular"
salsan@DESKTOP-E2MG55K:/mnt/s/GitHub/otu$ fc-match FreeMon
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
salsan@DESKTOP-E2MG55K:/mnt/s/GitHub/otu$ fc-match Free
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
salsan@DESKTOP-E2MG55K:/mnt/s/GitHub/otu$ fc-match FreeMono
FreeMono.ttf: "FreeMono" "Regular"
```